# Populating a temporary array to avoid using Preserve on a dynamic, multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

As a beginner to VBA I'm trying to learn most of this content ad-hoc, so pardon my dust.

I have a subroutine I'm writing for reading through lines in a text file. Each line is space delimited with ' as a text identifier. I require each line to be split into fields as a multidimensional array.

```
Sub ReadLines()
Dim LineValues() As String
Dim row As Long, col As Long
Dim DataArray() As String
Dim TempArray() As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "c:\mytextfile.txt"
row = 0
TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
Close TextFile
LineValues = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)

For X = LBound(LineValues) To UBound(LineValues) 
 If Len(Trim(LineValues(X))) <> 0 Then
 DataArray = Split(LineValues(X), "'") 
 col = UBound(DataArray)
 TempArray = DataArray
 ReDim DataArray(col, row) 
 For i = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)
 DataArray(i, row) = TempArray(i)
 Next i
 End If
 row = row + 1 
Next X
```

I came to this bit of code after struggling against the multidimensional problems with ReDim Preserve. (only being able to modify the last dimension) The multidimensional array in my text file will have unknown columns and rows depending on user input.

This code does the process correctly...but just can't store the array elements correctly! The intent above was to use a temporary array (TempArray) while I ReDim (and empty) the array I am interested in (DataArray) and then copy back the elements originally from DataArray into the resized dimensions.

However when stepping through the code I can see each row being placed correctly but then erased with each iteration at line,
    DataArray = Split(LineValues(X), "'")

I essentially have a matrix that is sized by the total number of rows but only by the number of columns on the last row (and only the values from the last row) as a result of this.

I realise why this is happening but can anyone here propose a solution? As a beginner this is all a bit maddening!

**EDIT, Full Problem Description**

To clarify fully, this is a subroutine I will call as part of a script reading through a text file which contains irrelevant data. This text file looks a little something like this, (vagueness of the references is intentional)

```
 '<irrelevant text I want to ignore until seeing pattern 'NumberOfVariables?'>
    ...
    ...
    NumberOfVariables?
    NUMBEROFVARIABLES
    'for the end user, I need to be able to pull information from each of these fields assigned to a variable to create strings as headers as per a specific format
'note that variable and variable type 
    Variable#1 VARIABLETYPE Location? LOCATION UNITS DESCRIPTION 'text for each field is enclosed as follows '' (code formatting on site prevents me doing this)
    Variable#2 VARIABLETYPE Location? LOCATION UNITS DESCRIPTION
    ...
    Variable#NUMBEROFVARIABLES
    ' from here there is a column of data that is assigned to each variable such that
    Variable#1Element1         Variable#2Element1       'etc until #NUMBEROFVARIABLES
    Variable#1Element2         Variable#2Element2 
    Variable#1Element3         Variable#2Element3 
    Variable#1FinalElement     Variable#2FinalElement
```

Main goal is use the script in original post to get these fields in a multidimensional matrix that I can then use against some conditional statements to get the header strings as per the end user desires.

From here I would then find a way to have the columns of data match up with each variable such that it can be automated into Excel.

A step further would be some sort of MsgBox w/ a pulldown that would select variables to copy across but that's pie in the sky thinking at my stage of development right now!

Comment: What do you intend to do with the final data? You could simply use an array of arrays.

Comment: You are rediming Dataarray every row.  This removes all data each time.  That needs to be moved outside the loop, but this requires that you know the largest extent of columns.  You could guess high.  Just FYI, there are native tools in Excel that will do this.

Comment: this is the reason why I dislike arrays. If I were you I would store the DataArray in a dictionary for each line and continue until complete. No resizing required for using a dictionary and also you will never have an array with empty values due to resizing the array to fit all data.

Comment: Seems to me you can find the number of rows from UBound(LineValues)? Then you can simply redim preserve for columns.

Comment: As @ScottCraner pointed out, your `ReDim` removes the data each time.  Instead, try `ReDim Preserve DataArray(col, row)`

Comment: @BruceWayne This approach, in the original script, hits the issue with ReDim Preserve only being able to change the last dimension. (thus leading me towards early baldness)

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers That seems like a nice way of simplifying  the problem, I will also try this separately.

Comment: @ClintStreet I have seen dictionary mentioned numerous times on this issue but I am more naturally familiar with the idea of an array. Once I have this up and running I can try expanding my horizons to functions such as dictionary, collection, array of arrays (@Rory), etc

Comment: @ScottCraner I did see that happening and you are right I could guess with reasonable accuracy and very little oversizing on the number of columns. I think I just got a bit set on the idea of conquering the issue! 

Excel does not (I think) natively do what I have mind, see above for edit, as I intend to call this sub as part of a larger script to read a particular section of the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've not tested it:

```
Sub ReadLines()

    Const FilePath$ = "c:\mytextfile.txt"

    Dim iFile%, c&, i&, j&, k&, Content$, Lines, Temp, Data

    c = 499
    Open FilePath For Input As #iFile
    Content = StrConv(InputB(LOF(iFile), iFile), vbUnicode)
    Close #iFile

    Lines = Split(Content, vbCrLf)
    ReDim Data(0 To UBound(Lines), 0 To c)

    For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        If Len(Trim$(Lines(i))) Then
            Temp = Split(Lines(i), "'")
            If k < UBound(Temp) Then k = UBound(Temp)
            If k > c Then
                c = k * 2
                ReDim Preserve Data(0 To UBound(Lines), 0 To c)
            End If
            For j = 0 To UBound(Temp)
                Data(i, j) = Temp(j)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve Data(0 To UBound(Lines), 0 To k)

End Sub
```

Comment: If k is > c then why not just use k as the array size definer ReDim Preserve Data(0 To UBound(Lines), 0 To k)? Just curious as to how this would work.

Comment: @JDonald Were you able to get this going?

Comment: @ExcelHero Sorry for delay (away to start writing responses to all this amazing and unexpected amount of input) but this almost worked a treat for what I asked in the original question. I was having a problem with the declaration of iFile so I took it out of your tidier approach and did it the way my <1 week of experience googling on the internet has taught me.
     `Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile`
     `Dim c&, i&, j&, k&, Content$, Lines, Temp, Data` This worked perfect after that slight change.

Comment: @ClintStreet I'm only guessing based on my reading up before hand, but is the k > c check before redefining c as 2k minimising the variations of ReDim Preserve in the array as a performance issue?

Comment: You don't want to use Redim Preserve to often I am guessing that is why making c = k * 2 would be a good way to eliminate that. IMO using a dictionary would be much better. Unfortunately I am a bit strapped for time these days so I was not able to provide an answer using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

> I require each line to be split into fields as a multidimensional array.

Well I don't know if this is actually true, because i'm not sure what you're ultimately *doing* with the data, but in any case, a super simple alternative would be to read the .txt file in to a workbook structure.

To do this, use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method with parameter: `TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierSingleQuote` (there are some additional optional parameters which may be needed depending on your use-case).

This should open the text file, properly delimited, in to the "fields" (Columns in the worksheet).

From there, you can assign the sheet's `UsedRange.Value` to a variant array.

Comment: As a total beginner to programming (never mind VBA)  it's quite possible I'm using the wrong tools or overthinking the problem.

I am aware of the import text delimited functions in Excel (I have recorded a macro and seen the True/False parameters you speak of) but this use of a variant for UsedRange.Value is a new approach to me. 

Excel Hero's approach below solved the original question but see my comment above  where I expanded the full task I am trying to accomplish to see if my approach is inefficient.